# Create a context menu with PyQt5

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a context menu and I saw some tuts in which they program the next code for example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, qApp, QMenu, QApplication


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Context menu')
        self.show()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        cmenu = QMenu(self)

        newAct = cmenu.addAction("New")
        openAct = cmenu.addAction("Open")
        quitAct = cmenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

        if action == quitAct:
            qApp.quit()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to implement in my code which have 2 modules but don't work:

main.py

```
import win0 as w0
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMenu

class Main(QMainWindow, w0.Ui_win0):
    win0 = None
    __win0_ui = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.win0 = QMainWindow()
        self.__win0_ui = w0.Ui_win0()
        self.__win0_ui.setupUi(self.win0)
        self.win0.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

win0.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidget, QFrame, QMenu, QMainWindow, qApp

class Table(QTableWidget, QMainWindow):

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        cmenu = QMenu(self)
        newAct = cmenu.addAction("New")
        openAct = cmenu.addAction("Open")
        quitAct = cmenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

        if action == quitAct:
            qApp.quit()        

class Ui_win0(object):
    def setupUi(self, win0):
        win0.setObjectName("win0")
        win0.resize(703, 757)
        win0.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29);"
                           "\ncolor: rgb(171, 171, 171);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(win0)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        self.table1 = Table(self.centralwidget)
        
        # Code...

        self.retranslateUi(win0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(win0)

    def retranslateUi(self, win0):
        # Code...
```

I don't paste all the code for don't make it too long but i wanted implement the example in the Table class because i want to expand some options or others depending that if the cursor is over the table list or in other place of the window.

What i'm doing wrong?

EDIT 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
For more clarity, the idea it's the next

[image]

The white boxes represent the context menu of the right click in differents places of the window

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I've to admit that your structure is not only wrong (for instance, multiple inheritance of QObject/QWidget is not allowed) but also really convoluted and very confusing. Can you clarify what you actually want to show as interface (a main window with a table widget), and what widget should show the menu? Finally, keep in mind that you should not try to mimic the behavior of pyuic generated files (as you did with the `Ui_win0` class); the concept behind those files is only used for designer files, and trying to do the same for ui created by code is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit for more clarity attaching and image of the interface that I want to make

Comment: Consider that having an interface with so much empty space is not a good thing, especially because the table needs more scrolling than it would be required if it could occupy at least the whole vertical space; also, I believe that you are not using any layout manager, which will have another *bad* side effect: if the window is resized to a smaller size (by the user, or by the system if the screen is not big enough), the table will be "clipped", possibly making the scrollbars unusable.

Comment: I'm not using all the space because i'm thinking in put other widgets in there in the future, with this example I'm just trying to understand how to make an context menu like I described above. It's just a reduced version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to provide a "template code", since what was provided is almost unusable for various reasons (wrong inheritance, unnecessary object layers, unrequired functions and implementations).

In the following example, I'm using a mix of two of the possible approaches to create menu events:

- implementation of `contextMenuEvent()` on a subclass
- [`customContextMenuRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal connection without subclassing

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        someAction = menu.addAction('')
        if index.isValid():
            someAction.setText('Selected item: "{}"'.format(index.data()))
        else:
            someAction.setText('No selection')
            someAction.setEnabled(False)
        anotherAction = menu.addAction('Do something')

        res = menu.exec_(event.globalPos())
        if res == someAction:
            print('first action triggered')


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central)
        self.table = Table(10, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addStretch()

        central.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        central.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.emptySpaceMenu)

    def emptySpaceMenu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction('You clicked on the empty space')
        menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Example()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As you can see, most of the structure you used was stripped away as unnecessary or redundant. This is a very important aspect: while keeping a highly explicit and "verbose" object structure usually allows better abstraction, overdoing so only makes things unnecessarily complex and very confusing, even to the programmer.